# Why can't I see windows WM_UNICHAR message?

Tags: winapi, unicode

I'm trying `WM_UNICHAR` message based on Charles Petzold's KeyView2 code, with some code enhancement by my own([code at github](https://github.com/chjfth/dailytools/tree/master/KeyView2)).

[MSDN: WM_UNICHAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-unichar) is quite vague on `WM_UNICHAR`'s relationship with the traditional `WM_CHAR` message, so I try it my own.

However, I never see `WM_UNICHAR` appear. On Win10.22H2, I bring up the IME and try to type in a "red apple" Ext-Unicode character(`U+1F34E`, UTF8: `F0 9F 8D 8E`, UTF-16LE: `D83C DF4E`), the unicode version of KeyView2 receives two `WM_CHAR` with wParam`D83C` and `DF4E`.

No `WM_UNICHAR` is received. Can someone tell me why? Thank you.

[image: Trying to type in a RED APPLE Ext-Unicode char]

[image: EXE code gets two WM_CHAR messages.]

[image: Never see WM_UNICHAR happen.]

Comment: Does your message pump contain a call to TranslateMessage in between GetMessage and DispatchMessage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my WM\_UNICHAR handler never called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378296/why-is-my-wm-unichar-handler-never-called)

Comment: It seems that `WM_CHAR` handles Unicode already. Maybe it does not handle Unicode in ANSI (old non-Unicode) apps, and for those apps you need `WM_UNICHAR` to handle some exotic input. ANSI app probably can't show that input, but it can at least handle it.

Comment: Sure I called `TranslateMessage`, otherwise, the IME floating window would not have appeared. The "Why is my WM_UNICHAR handler never called?" answer does not solve my baffle. I cannot agree with the saying "The WM_UNICHAR message is not sent natively by Windows, but only by 3rd party applications", If that is the case, then why Microsoft bother defining this message himself?

Comment: `WM_UNICHAR` is never generated by Windows itself. It's meant for IMEs to use to send character input to other applications. Not all IMEs will use it, and I expect very few applications will support it, but it's there as an option for them to try. If `WM_UNICHAR` falls through to `DefWindowProc` then `DefWindowProc` generates a standard `WM_CHAR` message.

Comment: If the window class is "Unicode" (as Microsoft uses the term), then TranslateMessage will post WM_CHAR with the character code in UTF-16--using two messages with the high and low surrogates for codepoints outside the BMP. If the window class is "ANSI" (as Microsoft uses the term), then TranslateMessage posts WM_CHAR with the character code in the current code page (which may, nowadays, be UTF-8). There was a time (pre-Vista?) in which TranslateMessage would post WM_UNICHAR to ANSI windows that opted in. Nowadays WM_UNICHAR is only for IME.