# Windows producing UTF8 sequence for ANSI version WM_CHAR? Why I cannot see it?

Tags: winapi, unicode

In today(2023.01)'s MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-char , Microsoft says that:

> ... Otherwise(using ANSI version of RegisterClass), the system provides characters in the current process code page, which **can be set to UTF-8** in Windows Version 1903 (May 2019 Update) and newer.

But, I just can NOT see WM_CHAR presenting Unicode character in UTF8 sequence. Am I doing wrong, or the document is wrong/misleading?

I do the experiments on Win10.21H2, using [Keyview2A.exe v1.8](https://github.com/chjfth/dailytools/tree/master/KeyView2), which is based on Charles Petzold's Keyview2 demo program in his famous book [Programming Windows 5th-ed (1998)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X).

I'm trying on Win10.21H2 .

### First, the non-UTF8ACP case to show that KeyviewA works OK.

I try to type a Chinese character **电**, which is U+7535, and GBK encoding `B5 E7`.

[image: non-UTF8APC, type in a non-ASCII char]

[image: non-UTF8APC, OK we get ANSI sequence in codepage 936]

### Second, the UTF8ACP case does NOT give KeyviewA UTF8 sequence.

I just got 0x3F(?), sigh!

[image: UTF8ACP, type in a Unicode char]

[image: UTF8ACP, does not see UTF8 sequence in WM_CHAR]

### Third, what about those characters from SBCS?

SBCS = Single-byte character set.
DBCS = Double-byte character set.
MBCS = Multi-byte character set. (generic name for SBCS, DBCS and 3+byte character set)

Most European countries use such character set.

Type in some Russian letters:

[image: Type in some Russian letters.]

Type in some Greek letters:

[image: Type in some Greek letters]

[20230121.c1] So far, I seem to have found out the rule about "enabling UTF8ACP", for an ANSI(narrow-char) program. Summarized below:

The IME produces Unicode value for any human-input character. When Windows need to send that character to KeyviewA, it does the following:

- Check the HKL value for the target HWND. Memo: KeyviewA itself can query this HKL value by `GetKeyboardLayout(0)`.
- Get the ANSI-codepage associated the HKL value(lets call it `curhkl`). This can be acquired by `curcodepage=GetLocaleInfo(LOWORD(curhkl), LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE, ...);`.
- Call `WideCharToMultiByte(curcodepage, ...)` to convert the Unicode value to MBCS sequence.

  - If the MBCS is a single byte(e.g. 0xE1), Windows sends one WM_CHAR message to Keyview2A with wParam=0xE1 .
  - If the MBCS is two bytes(e.g. 0xB5 0xE7), then Windows sends two WM_CHAR messages to Keyview2A with wParam=**0x3F**, both.

Comment: Does that program detect [`WM_UNICHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-unichar)?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71431386/

Comment: @JosefZ Is it though?

Comment: @GSerg I tries to capture WM_UNICHAR, as in this question [https://stackoverflow.com/q/75186875/151453] of mine, and I never received one, no matter in Keyview2A or in Keyview2U.

Comment: Perhaps adding [WM_IME_CHAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/wm-ime-char) to the keyboard messages logged by the key viewer program would help show what's going on.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like I need to answer my own question after some investigation. The answer is something that you and I cannot acquire by merely reading MSDN.

I did see UTF8 in ANSI WM_CHAR, but in a surprising way.

- First, turn on UTF8ACP on Windows 10.
- Second, add a Tibetan(藏语) keyboard layout.
- Third, run Keyview2A v1.9 (ANSI version) which I have just updated to deal with the very case.

Now, type some Tibetan characters into Keyview2A, and we see UTF8 sequence appear.

[image: Add Tibetan keyboard layout]

[image: Type some Tibetan characters into Keyview2A]

You see? **The three UTF8 bytes are sent in a single WM_CHAR message**, not across three WM_CHAR messages. This idea is OK because one UTF8 sequence has max length of 4 bytes which can be tucked in a WPARAM.

Now compare it with Keyview2U (the Unicode version), no matter UTF8ACP is on or off:

[image: Type some Tibetan characters into Keyview2U]

OK, U+0F45 is UTF8 [E0 BD 85], they match.

Something to mention:

- If Keyview2A runs in UTF8ACP-off env, it still gets 0x3F(`?`) in WM_CHAR.
- Why Tibetan is so special? I think that's because the industry never has defined a codepage for Tibetan(just call it *no-codepage charset*). To encode Tibetan text, you have to encode it in Unicode. Beside Tibetan, I think there are Bengali, Gujarati, Tamil etc.
- Does every no-codepage charset produce UTF8 sequence in one WM_CHAR message? No, as I find out later! Amharic(spoken in Ethiopia) is an example. It sends UTF8 sequence in a series of WM_CHAR messages, each for one byte. See image below.

[image: UTF8ACP, typing an Amharic letter]

-- What a damn inconsistency!

Final word today, Don't you think Microsoft's UTF8ACP enhancement to ANSI WM_CHAR is **crappy**? It enables Keyview2A to see no-codepage charset(like Tibetan)'s UTF8 sequence, but do NOT enable it to see those has-codepage charset's UTF8 sequence(you see above in my question, Keyview2A gets two 0x3F for a Chinese GBK character) -- genuinely ridiculous.

I really hope Keyview2A can get UTF8 sequence for every WM_CHAR -- and breaks many many legacy applications(by receiving wrong byte sequences for non-ASCII characters), and most people thinks that is what UTF8ACP should mean. No wonder Microsoft is still marking UTF8ACP feature as "Beta", and I guess the Beta status will keep going for many years, maybe 10~20 years.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft's support for UTF-8 is crappy.  You've been able to set your code page to 65001 for many years, but reportedly it was very buggy and I guess you've just tripped over those bugs.  It's an unfortunate state of affairs, because UTF-8 is a really wonderful encoding and all the flavors of *nix have adopted it almost universally.