# How to handle WM_CHAR with /utf-8 and UTF-8 manifest

Tags: c++, winapi, utf-8

I'm having trouble figuring out how to update my WM_CHAR handler to work with the new [/utf-8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8) execution mode + [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page). I have it working correctly if I use strings from source with unicode characters. The windows title and console will display them as they should, but now I want my user input to handle it correctly as well.

I can't find documentation about it anywhere, so at some point I tried to just figure it out manually but no luck.

So I try to print the data like this:

```
case WM_CHAR:
    println("WM_CHAR: 0x{:X}[{}]", (uint32)wParam, GetUTF8CharCount((uint32)wParam));
```

The count function is this:

```
static uint GetUTF8CharCount(uint32 c) {
    if (c <= 0x7F) {
        /* U+0000 ... U+007F */
        return 1;
    } else if (c < 0x07FF) {
        /* U+0080 ... U+07FF */
        return 2;
    } else if (c < 0xFFFF) {
        /* U+0800 ... U+FFFF */
        return 3;
    } else {
        /* U+10000 ... U+10FFFF */
        return 4;
    }
}
```

If I type 'ウ' in a textbox the following info prints:

```
[Info]: WM_CHAR: 0x4581[3]
[Info]: WM_CHAR: 0x4581[3]
[Info]: WM_CHAR: 0xA6[2]
```

[This website](https://onlinetools.com/utf8/convert-utf8-to-bytes) tells me that only the last byte is correct.
It makes no sense to me, how do I interpret this msg?

**Edit:**

Additionally I've printed the following info:

```
CPINFOEX cpInfo;
GetCPInfoEx(CP_ACP, 0, &cpInfo);
println("ACP: {}, IsWindowUnicode: {}", GetACP(), IsWindowUnicode(hWnd));
println("CPINFOEX: {{{}, {}, {}, {}, {}}}", cpInfo.CodePage, std::string(cpInfo.CodePageName), *((uint16*)cpInfo.DefaultChar), cpInfo.MaxCharSize, (uint32)cpInfo.UnicodeDefaultChar);
```

Result:

```
[Info]: ACP: 65001, IsWindowUnicode: 0
[Info]: CPINFOEX: {65001, 65001 (UTF-8), 63, 4, 65533}
```

To emphasize that it does work (if I add it directly in source):

[image: Window title]

[image: Output with emoji]

**Edit 2:**

It seems to be related to the active language. If I set my keyboard layout to US-international (my default), then press Win+; to type the  emoji I get `F0 9F 8E 89`, but switching to Japanese causes the `0x4581` to appear

Comment: Odd, I would have expected `ウ` to produce `E3 82 A6` as a UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: How did you register the window class receiving the `WM_CHAR` messages? How does the program behave when you're handling [`WM_UNICHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-unichar) messages instead?

Comment: `WM_UNICHAR` is not called at all right now. I change the `Character Set`  to `Not Set` and made sure all other WIN32 API calls are using the macro (aka `RegisterClassEx` is `RegisterClassExA`). Note that this was required to get the /utf-8 execution mode + manifest working correctly (and that does work)

Comment: I'm guessing there is some kind of length information encoded in the value. So you know how many `WM_CHAR` messages you'd have to collect ?

Comment: A UTF-8 stream carries that information implicitly

Comment: Note that `/utf-8` is not an execution mode, it's just a note to the compiler on how to interpret your source code and create string constants.

Comment: @MarkRansom Quote from the documentation: 
> You can use the /utf-8 option to specify both the source and execution character sets as encoded by using UTF-8. It's equivalent to specifying /source-charset:utf-8 /execution-charset:utf-8 on the command line.

Comment: @PaulSanders yes, but considering this isn't really a ' UTF-8 stream'  but a callback with values that is called 3 times in a row you'd need to somehow know when the last byte is send

Comment: Did you read the [documentation for `/execution-charset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/execution-charset-set-execution-character-set?view=msvc-170)?  *This character set is used for the internal representation of any string or character literals in the compiled code.*  I don't see anything on that page to indicate it affects run-time properties at all.

Comment: Side note: `GetUTF8CharCount` if statements should be < 0x800 and < 0x10000 (or <= 0x7ff and <= 0xFFFF).

Comment: Yes, exactly, so changing the representation of a string affects the runtime properties. I'm not sure what you're getting at though? This problem in particular is about the manifest change that sets the default codepage to also be UTF-8. Aka windows will handle your application differently

Comment: @MarkTolonen Ah thanks for the info, I got that from another library on GitHub. I'll inform them as well :)

Comment: `WM_CHAR` is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-char) as providing UTF-16 **codeunits** if the window is Unicode, otherwise codepage **codeunits** if the window is ANSI. Your use of `GetUTF8CharCount()` is wrong in either case, as it takes in a Unicode **codepoint** which `WM_CHAR` never provides (`WM_UNICHAR` does). `ウ` is Unicode codepoint U+30A6, and the fact that you are getting 3 events, where the first two have the same `wParam` value of `0x4581` (which is not related to either the UTF-8 or UTF-16 representation of `ウ`) is troubling...

Comment: ... If your window is registered as ANSI and your runtime ANSI codepage is UTF-8, you should get 3 `WM_CHAR` events with `wParam` values of `0xE3` `0x82` `0xA6`. If your window is registered as Unicode, you should get 1 `WM_CHAR` event with an `wParam` value of `0x30A6`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau any idea if there is an API call or something to confirm that's actually setup correctly? Also keep in mind that I was able to set the window title (using the ansi API) with an std::string that contains unicode characters

Comment: [`IsWindowUnicode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-iswindowunicode). Though, not using macros and relying on circumstantial environment state would make that immediately obvious by inspection.

Comment: Yes, good point. I can try to hardcode the ANSI versions to make sure there is nothing messing with it and see if that changes anything

Comment: `GetACP()` or `GetCPInfo/Ex(CP_ACP)` can confirm whether the codepage is really UTF-8 or not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've updated the question with the results

Comment: OK, so the window is ANSI and the codepage is UTF-8. But `0x4581` is still invalid for UTF-8. Something else is going on that we're not seeing. Please provide a complete [mcve]. In any case, you are still using `GetUTF8CharCount()` incorrectly. To get the length of a UTF-8 sequence, you can extract the length only from the **1st** `char` in the sequence (ie, `if (c & 0x80 == 0) return 1; if (c & 0xE0 == 0xC0) return 2; if (c & 0xF0 == 0xE0) return 3; if (c & 0xF8 == 0xF0) return 4; throw ...;`), or else you have to iterate the whole sequence (which you don't have access to in `WM_CHAR` alone)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have some new information. I managed to reproduce the same issue in a completely different project (I can still give a full repro tomorrow) and then figured out it's related to the active keyboard layout. Any ideas ?

Comment: What is `lParam` set to in these events? That will give you more information about each event, such as the keyboard scan code. Also have a look at [`WM_IME_CHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/wm-ime-char), as well as [WM_CHAR and charsets?](https://comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32.narkive.com/WmZ05MKd/wm-char-and-charsets) and [What's broken in the WM_KEYDOWN-WM_CHAR input model?](http://www.ngedit.com/a_wm_keydown_wm_char.html) for some useful ancillary info.

Comment: Ah `WM_IME_CHAR` sounds interesting. I'll have a look at that one tomorrow, I think that might solve it. Also lParam is always `1`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I managed to get it working with win32 unicode mode if you're interested (see my answer)

Comment: Unfortunately, the proposed answer avoids answering the question: Why does this not work as documented?

Comment: @IInspectable that is a good question. I couldn't figure that out. Only thing I know is that it worked fine on us international keyboard layout, just not on any other layout. If other layouts are used I'm getting non utf-8 values

Comment: Also see this page about a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191880/windows-producing-utf8-sequence-for-ansi-version-wm-char-why-i-cannot-see-it

Answer (score 0):

So after hours of tinkering with ANSI mode, I found that it only works in US-International keyboard layouts and any other layout will give invalid sequences. (Maybe a bug in windows?)

As a workaround, something that works in all languages while still being able to run with [UTF-8 codepage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page) enabled and the [/utf-8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8) flag set, is to use the Unicode utf-16 Win32 API. The idea is to setup everything in utf-8 mode **except** the Win32 window. So we should use `RegisterClass(Ex)W` and `CreateWindowW`. For the other API's like window title, we can use the `A` versions if we so wish and still have UTF-8 support.

If setup correctly `WM_CHAR` will send UTF-16 chars. It might send them in surrogate pairs, which you will need to combine into a codepoint.

```
case WM_CHAR: {
    if (IS_HIGH_SURROGATE(wParam)) {
        window->highSurrogate = (uint32_t)wParam; // Store the first uint16, we will need to wait for the second WM_CHAR message to get the complete pair
        break;
    }

    uint32_t codePoint;
    if (IS_SURROGATE_PAIR(window->highSurrogate, wParam)) { // Check if we have a complete pair now
        codePoint = ((window->highSurrogate - HIGH_SURROGATE_START) << 10) + ((uint32_t)wParam - LOW_SURROGATE_START) + 0x10000;
    } else { // Otherwise this is already the code point (in the lower unicode range)
        codePoint = (uint32_t)wParam;
    }

    window->highSurrogate = 0;

    ProcessChar(codePoint);
    break;
}
```

*Note that you have to store the `highSurrogate` in a temporary variable that is available for the next call to `WM_CHAR`*

So to recap;
[image: Set /utf-8]
[image: Use Unicode Character Set]

[image: Add minifest file]
*Make sure to place the file somewhere the compiler can find it. You **will not** get an error if it can't.*

`app.manifest` contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="MyAppName" version="1.0.0.0"/>
    <asmv3:application>
        <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2019/WindowsSettings">
            <activeCodePage>UTF-8</activeCodePage>
        </asmv3:windowsSettings>
    </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

To get the UTF-8 characters from the code point you can use the following code:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> ConvertCodePointToUTF8(uint32_t code) {
    std::vector<uint8_t> utf8_bytes;

    if (code <= 0x7F) { /* U+0000 ... U+007F */
        utf8_bytes.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(code));
    } else if (code <= 0x7FF) { /* U+0080 ... U+07FF */
        utf8_bytes.reserve(2);
        utf8_bytes.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(0xC0 | ((code >> 6) & 0x1F)));
        utf8_bytes.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(0x80 | (code & 0x3F)));
    } else if (code <= 0xFFFF) { /* U+0800 ... U+FFFF */
        utf8_bytes.reserve(3);
        utf8_bytes.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(0xE0 | ((code >> 12) & 0x0F)));
        utf8_bytes.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(0x80 | ((code >> 6) & 0x3F)));
        utf8_bytes.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(0x80 | (code & 0x3F)));
    } else {
        utf8_bytes.reserve(4);
        utf8_bytes.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(0xF0 | ((code >> 18) & 0x07)));
        utf8_bytes.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(0x80 | ((code >> 12) & 0x3F)));
        utf8_bytes.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(0x80 | ((code >> 6) & 0x3F)));
        utf8_bytes.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(0x80 | (code & 0x3F)));
    }

    return utf8_bytes;
}

...

auto utf8Char = ConvertCodePointToUTF8(codePoint);
std::cout << std::format("WM_CHAR Result: {}, CodePoint: 0x{:X}\n", std::string{ utf8Char.begin(), utf8Char.end() }, codePoint);
```

(For correct console output you might also need to call `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);`)

[image: Result]

[image: Japanese Chars]

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, it's a workaround - using Windows native UTF-16 and converting on the fly to UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, if anyone knows how to get it working I'd be more then happy to accept that as the answer. For now I'm gonna say that it's a bug in Windows that I can't resolve. For me this is the answer to my problem, which was that I needed it to work with normal strings for utf-8 but still have the ability to input any character in any keyboard layout. I've made a slight change in wording to emphasize this